# WPF disable ListBox autosizing in uniform grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

i do have the following structure:

```
<UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Columns="6"  DockPanel.Dock="Right"  >
  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <DockPanel Background="#FF393939"  >
          <Label Content="{lex:Loc Site}" Foreground="#FFE0E0E0"/>
      </DockPanel>
      <ListBox Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Sites.View}" DisplayMemberPath="Name.ActualTranslation">
      </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>...
```

These stackpanels in my UniformGrid should be spreaded over the whole MainWindow (or View)... Still if there is an item in a Listbox which has a longer string which needs more place than the standard width it autofits the string and i have to scroll vertically.

I dont want the listview to gain the width if the content has not enough place.
I also have a scrollviewer in my MainWindow in which this view is placed...

What can i do that the uniform grid stays the same width like the MainWindow-...

I've already tried to give a name to the MainWindow and Bind the width to something like this: `Width="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=ActualWdith}"` ..

though i get the error:

`Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=MainWindow'. BindingExpression:Path=ActualWdith; DataItem=null;`

What can i do to fix this issue?
If you need more information or my error description isnt clear dont hesitate to ask.

**UPDATE:**
how it should be: 
[image]

behavior when the text is too long:
[image]
and a scrollbar appears on the bottom..

Comment: Binding to the `ActualWidth` seems like a bad idea, but it shouldn't be necessary at all. The `UniformGrid` should stay the same size if set to stretch. Can you show a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access a WPF object by name it needs to have `x:Key="name"` which wasn't shown in your code above, i.e.

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow" ....
```

Alternatively you can walk back up the tree until you find an object of the correct type,

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MainWindow}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can simply change the way you show the text to constrain its width

```
<ListBox Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Sites.View}" DisplayMemberPath="Name.ActualTranslation">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="200"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: i dont know a MaxWidth from the ListBox or the containing textblocks... because this is relative to the size of the window.